# Trying to make an banking deposit with player input

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I'm fairly new to coding spigot but I am trying to make a banking script where the player would click the deposit button and be prompted to type in the amount of money they want to deposit. However, when this happens in game, it automatically determines the input as 0 and doesn't give the player enough time to type in their message. Here is the code:

```
private void deposit(Player p, String gang) {

    deposited.add(p);
    p.closeInventory();
    p.sendMessage(ChatManager.Feedback("jahseh", "Please type how much money you want to deposit"));
    int input = (int) MyListener.typed;
    if (Main.getEconomy().getBalance(p) >= input){
        Main.getEconomy().bankDeposit(gang, input);
        p.sendMessage(ChatManager.Feedback("jahseh", "You have deposited " + input + " stonebucks into your gang's bank."));
    }
    if (Main.getEconomy().getBalance(p) < input){
        p.sendMessage(ChatManager.Feedback("alert", "You are trying to deposit more money than you currently have!"));
    }

    }



public void input (AsyncPlayerChatEvent event){
Player p = event.getPlayer();
String typed = event.getMessage();
if(Bank.deposited.contains(p)) {
    Bank.deposited.remove(p);
    event.setCancelled(true);
}
```

}
}

Answer (score 0):

You have to wait for the listener to be executed, and only once it has been executed, run the code below.